# Appending iterated rows to new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to python, and I could use a push in the right direction for what I think should be (?) a pretty simple problem. I've got a dataframe (genres_df) with one column:

```
              0
0        Horror
1        Comedy
2       Fantasy
3     Adventure
4         Drama
5     Animation
6         Crime
...
```

and a dataframe (df) with 3 columns--one for each genre associated with the film, and one row for each film I'm looking at):

```
    0   1   2
0   Horror  Short   None
1   Horror  Short   None
2   Comedy  Horror  Short
3   Comedy  Horror  Short
4   Fantasy Horror  Short
...
```

I want to count the number of rows in the dataframe genres that contain each item in genres_df. I was able to do this by hand, with a sum line:

```
sum(df[0] == 'Comedy') + sum(df[1] == 'Comedy') + sum(df[2] == 'Comedy')
```

I know this works, because there is a Horror item in each row, and there are 78471 rows in df.

I want to get a dataframe that has two columns: the genre (from genres_df) and the count of rows in which that genre appears, across any of the columns in df. Like so

```
  0      1
0 Horror 78471
1 Comedy 9903
...
```

Here's what I've got so far:

```
df_counts = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['genre','count'])
for i in genres_df[0]:
    s_row = pd.Series(i,sum(df[0]==i)+sum(df[1]==i)+sum(df[2]==i))
    df_counts.append(s_row,ignore_index=True)
```

But this doesn't work. It seems to be the closest I've gotten, though. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to do is the following

- melt your dataframe (i.e turn the column into rows)
- apply a groupby operation & count

Finally.

- filter the genre column with the genre's from your first df

---

```
df1 =  pd.melt(df,value_name='genre').groupby('genre',
                            as_index=False).agg(count=('genre','count'))  


print(df1)

     genre  count
0   Comedy      2
1  Fantasy      1
2   Horror      5
3     None      2
4    Short      5
```

---

```
final = df1[df1['genre'].isin(all_genre['0'])]

     genre  count
0   Comedy      2
1  Fantasy      1
2   Horror      5
```

As a side note - if you're using methods outside of the pandas API then you're most likely doing something incorrectly (as in against the design of the library)

Comment: Thank you, @Umar.H! This is very helpful. When you refer to methods outside of the pandas api, are you talking about append or sum?

Comment: @TonyaHowe exactly that, pandas has its own `.sum()` function the native pandas one will be slow and most likely take an iterable where as pandas uses set operations, so it's much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is right but `append` like any other pandas operation does not mutate the dataframe by default, so you have to reassign it (or use `inplace=True`)

```
df_counts = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['genre','count'])
for i in genres_df[0]:
    s_row = pd.Series(i,sum(df[0]==i)+sum(df[1]==i)+sum(df[2]==i))
    df_counts = df_counts.append(s_row,ignore_index=True)
```